# How to configure a strategy or strategy.close() functiuon to close entries if they reach a profit percentage?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

For example I want to close an Entry in case it makes 10% profit.

Example code:

```
long_entry = WhenSomethingSomething

strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when=long_entry)

if … (?)
    strategy.close("Long", "Long", ???=???)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any additional conditions, you should do it with `strategy.exit()`

Example:

```
long_entry = WhenSomethingSomething
long_tp_price = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + (0.10))

strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when=long_entry)

if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit("LE", "Long", limit=long_tp_price
```

If you want to close your position conditionally, and see if you are in at least 10% profit, you should do a similar calculation.

Example:

```
long_entry = WhenSomethingSomething
long_exit = WhenSomethingElse
long_tp_price = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + (0.10))

strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when=long_entry)

if (long_exit and (high >= long_tp_price))
    strategy.close("Long")
```